# jQuery Knob partially read only

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-knob

I have a collection of jQuery knobs on my page that represent percentages.  Each knob can have a value from 0-100, however, each subsequent knob should not have a value less than the previous knob.  Essentially I want to make part of the knob read only - to prevent the user from dragging the value below the previous knob's value - similar to a 'min' value.

Example

- Knob 1 25%
- Knob 2 50%  (min value still 0, max 100, but the value has to be greater than 25)
- Knob 3 75%
- Knob 4 100%

I have tried binding to the 'change' event on the knob, but that is not giving me what I want. Below I'm binding to the change event to try to limit the value - this is hard coded to test the simple use case. I am probably going to want to bind to the 'draw' event to limit the values on animation but haven't got that far.

```
        $(this).trigger('configure', {
        'change': function (v) {
            console.log("Updating value " + v);
            if(v < 25) {
              console.log("Updating value");
              this.cv = 25;
            }
        }
    });
```

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? can you share your code so we can have an idea on where to add the missing pieces? - initial thought is to set the `data-max` and `data-min` values after an 'on change' event (like you suggested) but it's hard to tell the specifics of why your code is not working without looking at your code :)

Comment: @blurfus - the problem with data-max and data-min (min/max) is that it recalibrates the knob such that if you have a min as 25 then the knob is from 25 - 100, I need 0-100, just restricted so you can't select less than 25%

Comment: That's a tough one... I have not been able to find a practical solution. The best I can think of is to implement a validate() function or similar but the validation checks are basically the same you are doing on your 'on change' event.  Sorry, I have no additional help ATM

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the best way to do it, but you can manipulate the `angleOffset` and `angleArc` options of the dial based on the value of the previous one. For example, if you have two dials:

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" value="75" id="dial1">
<input type="text" value="75" id="dial2">
```

Your javascript would be something like this:

```
$(function () {
    $("#dial1").knob({
            'change': function (v) {
            $('#dial2')
                .trigger(
                'configure', {
                    'angleOffset': (v / 100 * 360),
                    'angleArc': ((100-v) / 100 * 360),
                    'min': v,
            });
        }
    });
    $("#dial2").knob();
});
```

As for the empty space left in the dial, you can fix that by setting the canvas background to an image of a full knob.

**CSS**

```
canvas {
    background: url('http://imgur.com/aeTBhL9.png');
}
```

Here's a [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/kjZwR/3/).

Comment: Actually I think that might work for me.  I started playing with the arc yesterday, this looks workable.